# Delete a line (name, contactnumber, emailaddress) by just searching for name in a phonebook

Tags: python, function

Good evening, I have a phonebook code but I am missing the delete feature. I cannot seem to make the delete feature work. All other features like insert, view, add contacts are working already.

I created a phnoebook txt file to store any entries.

```
phonebook = "d://phonebook.txt"
pbfile = open(phonebook, "a+")
pbfile.close


def show_main_menu():
    ''' Show main menu for Phone List '''
    print("\n   *** Phone List Menu ***\n"+
          "------------------------------------------\n"+
          "Enter 1, 2, 3 or 4:\n"+
          "1: Display Your Contacts Records\n" +
          "2: Add a New Contact Record\n"+
          "3: Search your contacts\n"+
          "4: Delete a Contact Record\n"+
          "5: Quit\n**********************")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == "1":
        pbfile = open(phonebook, "r+")
        file_contents = pbfile.read()
        if len(file_contents) == 0:
            print("Phone List is empty")
        else:
            print (file_contents)
        pbfile.close
        user_entry = input("Press Enter to Return to Main Menu ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "2":
        enter_contact_record()
        user_entry = input("Press Enter to Return to Main Menu ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "3":
        search_contact_record()
        user_entry = input("Press Enter to Return to Main Menu ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "4":
        delete_contact_record()
        user_entry = ("Please Enter to Return to Main Menu ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice== "5":
        print("Thanks for using Phone List")
    else:
        print("Wrong choice, Please Enter [1 to 5]\n")
        user_entry = input("Press Enter to Return to Main Menu ...")
        show_main_menu()
```

I added the main menu above to show the menu of the phone book, there should be another choice to delete a contact.

The following code is to search for contact. It will show if a contact is already in the phone book but will mention not on record if there is no contact by the name they searched.

```
        
def search_contact_record():
    ''' This function is used to searches a specific contact record '''
    contact_search = input("Enter First name to search for contact record: ")

    contact_search = contact_search.title()
    pbfile = open(phonebook, "r+")
    file_contents = pbfile.readlines()
     
    found = False   
    for line in file_contents:
        if contact_search in line:
            print("You searched for:", end=" ")
            print (line)
            found=True
            break
    if  found == False:
        print("There's no contact Record in Phone List with name = " + contact_search )
```

The next function is to enter contact and add it to the phonebook txt file created in the beginning.

```
def enter_contact_record():
    ''' It  collects contact info firstname, last name, email and phone '''
   
    first = input('Enter First Name: ')
    first = first.title()
    last = input('Enter Last Name: ')
    last = last.title()
    phone = input('Enter Phone number: ')
    email = input('Enter E-mail: ')
    contact = ("[" + first + " " + last + ", " + phone + ", " + email +  "]\n")
    pbfile = open(phonebook, "a")
    pbfile.write(contact)
    print( "This contact\n " + contact + "has been added successfully!")

#def delete_contact():
    

show_main_menu()
```

I got confused on the part how to delete the contact from the txt phonebook. Last delete lines I have trying was the following

```
def delete_contact_record():
            #Initiate a name variable
    contact_delete = input('Enter the name of the contact you wish to delete: ').title()
    
    pbfile = open(phonebook, "r+")
    file_contents = pbfile.readlines()
    
    found = False   
    for line in file_contents:
        if contact_delete in line:
            confirm = input('Are you sure you wish to delete '+contact_delete+' y/n?: ')
            print(confirm)
            
            if confirm == 'y':
                del phonebook[contact_delete]
            found = True
            
    if found == False:
        print('That contact does not exist! Return to the main menu to enter the contact')
```

it works up to the line asking for confirmation y/n. But when I enter Y, I get a `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion`

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check edited lines for the delete_contact

Comment: Your problem is with this line `del phonebook[contact_delete]`, `phonebook` is the name of the file, so that command is telling Python you're trying to delete some part of the string, which it doesn't support (and which isn't at all what you want anyway). Where do you really need to delete the entry from? And how do you expect that change to end up in the phonebook file?

Comment: The goal is to delete a record (name, phonenumber, emailaddress) by searching for the name.

Comment: Some unrelated problems I'm seeing:
1. Your `user_entry =` line for menu option 4 is missing the `input` call. So it skips the prompt.
2. You end each menu action with `show_main_menu()`. This isn't a GOTO, it's a method call, and it's recursive, so you'll effectively leak system resources every action. Instead, you should have a `while True:` as the first line of `show_main_menu`, and replace every `show_main_menu()` with `continue`. This pattern is what we call an "event loop."

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I revised my lines with your suggestions,

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your phone book is a flat file. As such, a deletion is "rewrite the entire file, but without the deleted record."

This is, needless to say, very inefficient.

You will also have problems in the future with spurious matches for searches, since `contact_search in line` is perfectly happy to match parts of names.

Personally, I'd recommend using an [SQLite3 database](https://sqlite.org/index.html) instead of a flat file ([SQLite3 support is built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) to Python). SQLite3 databases are actually single files, but you can use almost all of the SQL language to perform structured queries, and let it manage the file for you.

If writing SQL is too daunting, the [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) Python package can help by making database tables work like Python classes.

Comment: Hi, Mike. I thought of using the sqlite but the requirement is that it should be saved as a flat file. I googled and the few resources I found on how to rewrite the file without the record to delete is not making sense for me.

Comment: It's a stupid requirement. SQLite3 works like a flat file anyway.